# What does the title of the movie "A Scanner Darkly" mean?

Tags: word-order, pop-culture

I've seen the film (a long time ago) but I don't understand the title.

A noun followed by an adverb just doesn't make sense. What am I missing here?

Comment: The makers of the movie are playing on the phrase ["a mirror (glass), darkly"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b&q=a+mirror+darkly&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCjNnf1qnRAhWGsFQKHTZJA2YQvwUIGCgA&biw=1024&bih=584&bav=on.2,or.&ech=1&psi=zYltWILyJ4bh0gK2ko2wBg.1483573826601.3&ei=zYltWILyJ4bh0gK2ko2wBg&emsg=NCSR&noj=1&gfe_rd=cr) It seems to originate in 1 Corinthians 13:12.

Comment: Cascabel's got it. The verse (AV) is "For now we see **through a glass, darkly**; but then face to face: now I know in part; but then shall I know even as also I am known."

Comment: The significance of the title is revealed in Chapter 13 of the book, in a conversation between the protagonist and two psychologists, as they discuss his impaired brain function. He has difficulty recognizing himself in video recordings (made with a scanner), and the psychologists explain that his brain is processing input in a mirrored fashion. The protagonist then reflects on St. Paul's letter to the Corinthians.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a comment, our seasonally named Cascabel wrote:

> The makers of the movie are playing on the phrase ["a mirror (glass), darkly"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b&q=a+mirror+darkly&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCjNnf1qnRAhWGsFQKHTZJA2YQvwUIGCgA&biw=1024&bih=584&bav=on.2,or.&ech=1&psi=zYltWILyJ4bh0gK2ko2wBg.1483573826601.3&ei=zYltWILyJ4bh0gK2ko2wBg&emsg=NCSR&noj=1&gfe_rd=cr) It seems to originate in 1 Corinthians 13:12.

Also in a comment, StoneyB also wrote:

> Cascabel's got it. The verse (AV) is "For now we see **through a glass, darkly**; but then face to face: now I know in part; but then shall I know even as also I am known."

jlovegren says in a comment:

> The significance of the title is revealed in Chapter 13 of the book, in a conversation between the protagonist and two psychologists, as they discuss his impaired brain function. He has difficulty recognizing himself in video recordings (made with a scanner), and the psychologists explain that his brain is processing input in a mirrored fashion. The protagonist then reflects on St. Paul's letter to the Corinthians.

Comment: To clarify a bit more: the phrase in Corinthians is rendered in modern translations as "through a mirror, dimly", but, like many well-known expressions from the King James Bible, "through a glass, darkly" has become absorbed into the language.